# Compile a TensorFlow Lite project for microcontrollers with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gcc, makefile

I just downloaded the TensorFlow repository from github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow (v.2.3.1)).
I included it in my C++ project. After I make my Makefile I got the error:

```
make
arm-none-eabi-gcc -L -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra --pedantic -DSTM32 -DSTM32F7 -DSTM32F746xx -DSTM32F746NGHx -DSTM32F746G_DISCO -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mthumb -specs=nosys.specs  -DNDEBUG -nostartfiles -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=EMNIST.map -I ./inc -I ./lcd/inc -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Drivers/BSP/STM32746G-Discovery -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Utilities/Log -I ./../../STM32F7_library/Drivers/BSP/Components/ft5336   -c -o ../../TensorFlow_library/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.o ../../TensorFlow_library/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.c
../../TensorFlow_library/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.c:16:46: fatal error: tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.h"
```

I don't know why there is this error. Do I have to change all includes in the TensorFlow library from absolute paths to relative ones?
Or can I set some flags in the Makefile or something like this that I can use the absolute paths?
Can anyone?
Thanks!

Comment: Tensorflow is a Google project, and Google has its own peculiar ideas about building native code. I'd not recommend it to beginners. `make` is how the rest of the world builds software, but Google uses its own `bazel` tool.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
But it should work. In the examples on github they also use make but mbed compiler instead of gcc and it works.
In an other project I just used a little part of the TF Lite library and changed all include paths to relative ones and this worked too.
But I don't want to change the include paths for the whole library when there is a new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
In your Makefile you have to include the directory of your TensorFlow library.

This part of my Makefile looks in my case like this:\

```
Includes and Defines\
INCLUDES += -I ./inc\
INCLUDES += -I ./lcd/inc\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Drivers/CMSIS/Include\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Drivers/BSP/STM32746G-Discovery\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Utilities/Log\
INCLUDES += -I ./STM32F7_library/Drivers/BSP/Components/ft5336\
INCLUDES += -I ./TensorFlow_library
```

The TensorFlow library is stored in the "TensorFlow_library" folder.
When you include it like showed below you can use the TensorFlow library with absolute paths.